# How to cite ITUT document using BiBTeX?

Tags: citing

How to cite ITUT document like this one
http://www.itu.int/md/T05-FG.IPTV-C-0139/en
with IEEEtr style ?

Comment: This really depends on what citation standard you're using (or wether you're using BibTeX or `biblatex`).

Comment: BiBTeX , IEEE style

Comment: Any help with this question?

Comment: Again, are you using BibTeX or `biblatex` or just formatting the references yourself? In any case I suspect the [IEEE Citation Reference](http://www.ieee.org/documents/ieeecitationref.pdf) will tell you how to cite ITU documents because it sounds like something you'd do fairly regularly in IEEE fields.